# updating to rails 6, but "activerecord-session_store (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on actionpack (>= 5.2.4.1)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile, actionpack

I ran `bundle update rails` and got this. I'm stumped. If `activerecord-session_store` 2.0 depends on a version of `actionpack` between 5.2.4.1 and above, and if actionpack is a dependency of Rails 6, shouldn't this be ok?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
 In Gemfile:
  activerecord-session_store (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.0.0, which depends on
   actionpack (>= 5.2.4.1)

 rails (~> 6.0.3.6) was resolved to 6.0.3.6, which depends on
  actionpack (= 6.0.3.6)

 devise (~> 4.2) was resolved to 4.8.0, which depends on
  responders was resolved to 3.0.1, which depends on
   actionpack (>= 5.0)
```

My gemfile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.5.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3.6'
gem 'pg', ' 0.18.3'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3', '~> 1.75', require: false
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1'
gem 'pagy', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.2'
gem 'activerecord-session_store', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '3.7.2'
gem 'aasm', '~> 5.0'
gem 'redis', '~> 4.1', '>= 4.1.3'
gem 'sidekiq', '~> 6.0', '>= 6.0.4'
gem 'local_time', '~> 2.1'
gem 'stripe', '~> 5.11'
gem 'stripe_event', '~> 2.3'
gem 'lockbox', '~> 0.4.8'
gem 'mailgunner', '~> 2.4'
gem 'rack-attack'
gem 'honeypot-captcha', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
gem 'rack-timeout', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'pry', '0.13.1'
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.11'
gem 'shrine', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'marcel', '~> 0.3.3'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.1'
gem 'json', '~> 2.3', '>= 2.3.1'
```

Comment: actionpack needs to be version `6.0.3.6` for this to work I believe, what version is it in your lock file?

Comment: Lockfile says `actionpack (6.0.3.6)`

Comment: Then what you shared is not the issue

Comment: It would be better if you can include the full error in the post. You can highlight a certain part but including the error in full is useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm; if I try `bundle install` with your `Gemfile` I get

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "marcel":
  In Gemfile:
    marcel (~> 0.3.3)

    rails (~> 6.0.3.6) was resolved to 6.0.3.6, which depends on
      activestorage (= 6.0.3.6) was resolved to 6.0.3.6, which depends on
        marcel (~> 1.0.0)
```

So try updating the version of `marcel` in your `Gemfile` to `"~> 1.0.0"` and then `bundle update rails marcel`.

Comment: HOW??? did that fix everything?? my error output was actually a lot longer, but i was only including the relevant bits. the marcel errors were down much further. somehow this fixed everything in one fell swoop

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's hard to find the specific dependency that's stopping everything from upgrading as bundler is dumping out all of the dependencies.

A tip is to delete the `Gemfile.lock` and then `bundle install` - that will tell you if there is at least **a** solution to the dependencies in your `Gemfile`. Once you've got a `Gemfile` that works you can restore (from git) your `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle update` the gems who's versions you've changed.